# Doctrine 2.0 vs 2.1 cascade remove OneToMany

Tags: doctrine-orm

Hello I have problem when trying to cascade remove entities in OneToMany relations.
After a few hours of debugging I tried to downgrade the doctrine from the latest 2.1.2 to 2.0.2 and It suddenly starts working.

Imagin two entities Company and Address in relation 1:N.

```
/**
 * @Entity
 */
class Company extends Entity
{

 /**
  * @var integer
  * @id @Column(type="integer")
  * @generatedValue
  */
 private $id;

 /**
  * @var Collection
  * @OneToMany(targetEntity="Address",mappedBy="company", cascade={"persist","remove"})
  */
 private $addresses;
}



/**
 * @Entity
 */
class Address extends Entity
{

 /**
  * @var integer
  * @id @Column(type="integer")
  * @generatedValue
  */
 private $id;

 /**
  * @var Company
  * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="Company", inversedBy="addresses")
  * @JoinColumn(name="company_id", referencedColumnName="id",nullable=false)
  */
 private $company;
}
```

when I try to remove the entity Company, I would like the assigned addresses will be removed as well.

```
$em->remove($company);
$em->flush();
```

In doctrine 2.1.2 the deletion of addresses is not performed so the integrity constraint fails. In version 2.0.2 there it works perfectly. Wierd thing on it is, if I use EntityAudit extension https://github.com/simplethings/EntityAudit the LogRevisionListener is corretly versioning the addresses entities (set them revtype = DEL) in doctrine 2.1.2 (of course in 2.0.2 as well) but the UnitOfWork is not removing it.

Is there any difference how to handle cascade removing in 2.0.2 and in 2.1.2?

Thank you very much

Comment: I stumbled on this problem today too, I am using 2.1.6. :/

Comment: Well I have to correct my self, it works for me now! I was using `cascade={"all"}` but when I changed it in `cascade={"remove"}` everything started to work just fine.

Comment: Although I have to say that probably my problem may not be completely due to the annotation set or to Doctrine itself, because I am doing intensive manipulation on the entities and, after some test on the combination of the cascade options I found out that the `"merge"` option was the one giving problems.

Hope it helps anyway :)

Answer (score 10):

Try using this on the `addresses` attribute of your `Company` Class

```
@OneToMany(targetEntity="Address",mappedBy="company", 
cascade={"persist"}, orphanRemoval=true)
```

Comment: I'm using doctrine 2.2.3 and still same. Had to add orphanRemoval=true. Kind of strange because Im not removing the one side so not creating any orphans. Maybe because the many side is the owning side and I'm removing from the one side. Updates work because the many side is the owning side and I'm both using `$this->addSomething(theThing)` and `theThing->setSomething($this)` where as if I'm deleting theThing there is no setting something, only `$this->removeSomething(theThing)`

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem... Relations were added or updated, but not deleted, even if I had cascade: [persist, remove].

I found out that I didn't need the "remove" attribute in "cascade", but I had to add the orphanRemoval: true.

I was going crazy, you made my day!

Answer (score 1):

I have met the same problem and i have solved him with that code :

```
$em->remove($object);
$em->flush();
$em->remove($user);
$em->flush();
```

Maybe you can use a `findAll` on your `company` for the addresses and remove this with a `foreach` like that :

```
// Return all the addresses of the company
$addresses = $em->getRepository(...)->findAllAddressesByCompany($company);
$em->remove($company);
foreach ($address in $addresses)
{
    $em->remove($address);
}
```

That's not a very good method but for now, that's all I've found.

Comment: I have solved it out downgrading the doctrine :) thanks, but it is not the method whaich I am looking for :( it could be probably a bug (or a feature?)